# iPhone, PHP, MySQL communication

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xcode

A noob here.....

I'm looking for a tutorial on coding in Xcode that will retrieve data from MySQL server with PHP. 
To be clear on what I want, the MySQL database is on Server side, and the iphone user can only get data and not changing it. And it is a native iphone application, not a Web application.

This should common since there are so many apps using this technique but I still couldn't get myself up to it. I have installed MAMP on my MAC.

Any good source to learn this is really really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first link in Google for 'iphone php mysql tutorial'

http://icodeblog.com/2009/10/29/iphone-coding-tutorial-creating-an-online-leaderboard-for-your-games/

Comment: link is dead now. googling 'iphone php mysql tutorial' is still good advice though